# Bloquear a função btprevious2.setOnTouchListener

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma aplicação onde e uso o método `btprevious2.setOnTouchListener` para realizar a mudança rápida de página.

```
btprevious2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            private Handler handler;

            @Override 
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch(event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        if (handler != null) return true;
                        handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(action, 500);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (handler == null) return true;
                        handler.removeCallbacks(action);
                        handler = null;
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }

            Runnable action = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(verificacao())
                    {
                        previussalve();
                        return;
                    }else{
                        if (page2>1)
                            page2--;
                        else
                            page2=60;
                        setacursor(page2);
                        escrevebotao();
                        if (page2<10)
                            pageview2.setText("0"+String.valueOf(page2));
                        else pageview2.setText(String.valueOf(page2));

                    }


                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1);
                }
            };
        });
```

A questão é que quero que isso só funcione se uma outra função que eu tenho retornar falso.

O seguinte modo abaixo não funciona, mas vale a ideia

```
        if(!verificacao())
    {
    btprevious2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        private Handler handler;

        @Override 
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch(event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (handler != null) return true;
                    handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(action, 500);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (handler == null) return true;
                    handler.removeCallbacks(action);
                    handler = null;
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }

        Runnable action = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {


                    if (page2>1)
                        page2--;
                    else
                        page2=60;
                    setacursor(page2);
                    escrevebotao();
                    if (page2<10)
                        pageview2.setText("0"+String.valueOf(page2));
                    else pageview2.setText(String.valueOf(page2));




                handler.postDelayed(this, 1);
            }
        };
    });
    }
```

Como resolvo?

Resumindo, só quero que a função `btprevious2.setOnTouchListener` funcione se minha função de verificação retorne falso caso contrário quero que faça nada.

Comment: Tá difícil de entender o que queis fazer, porém, Pelo que eu entendi, tens que colocar a condição `if (!verificacao())` envolvendo o `switch(event.getAction())` ou seja, logo que entra na função `onTouch()`.

Comment: paulo consegui fazendo diferente, bloqueando a ação. 
coloquei o if dentro do run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de por a condição de verificação dentro dos `case` para que tenha efeito ou não, como queiras.

Fica o exemplo:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    if(!verificacao())
    {
        if (handler != null) return true;
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(action, 500);
    } 
    break;
```

Comment: acabei colocando dentro do run mas assim funciona tbm acredito vou testar

Answer (score 0):

***Consegui assim:***

```
Runnable action = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if(!verificacao())
        {
            if (page2>1)
                page2--;
            else
                page2=60;
            setacursor(page2);
            escrevebotao();
            if (page2<10)
                pageview2.setText("0"+String.valueOf(page2));
            else pageview2.setText(String.valueOf(page2));
        }

        handler.postDelayed(this, 1);
    }
};
```

Coloquei a verificação dentro do `run()`, e bloqueei toda a ação. 
**contra:** o programa fica ali enquanto não for solto o botão